# When will SQL Server Choose a Hash Join over a Merge Join?

Tags: sql-server, hash, merge

I have a large query with many joins that I am trying to tune, and one warning sign is that there are many, many hash joins being used throughout. I went down to the base of the query tree and went to the first join there, which is an inner join.

Table A is using a clustered index scan to retrieve its data, which is sorted on the join column.
Table B is using a nonclustered index scan, which is also sorted on the join column.

When I join just these two tables in isolation, and select the same set of columns, the optimizer uses a merge join. The sets being joined are approximately the same size, and not very large (<5,000 rows).

What could explain the optimizer choosing the hash join over the merge join in this case?

EDIT

As requested, I have added a few more details. The index definitions are:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX NCL_Asset_Issuer_MergeInduce ON Asset.IssuerCompanyId (CompanyId)INCLUDE (IsPrivate,HasPublicEquity,Ticker,FinancialTemplateID,BondTicker,SICOther1ID,SICOther4ID,SICSandPID,SICOther3ID,SICMoodyID,CurrencyTypeID,SecondaryAnalystID,AnalystID,SICOshaID,SecondaryBondTicker,FiscalYearEnd,EquityExchangeID);

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX NCL_Asset_IssuerCustom_IssuerId ON Asset.IssuerCustom (IssuerID) INCLUDE (Text3,ListItem1ID,ListItem5ID,ListItem3ID,ListItem2ID,Version,text4,TextLong15,ListItem6ID)
```

The following query will return a merge join, as I mentioned earlier:

```
SELECT IsPrivate,HasPublicEquity,Ticker,FinancialTemplateID,BondTicker,SICOther1ID,SICOther4ID,SICSandPID,SICOther3ID,SICMoodyID,CurrencyTypeID,SecondaryAnalystID,AnalystID,SICOshaID,SecondaryBondTicker,FiscalYearEnd,EquityExchangeID,ic.ListItem2Id,ic.ListItem3ID,ic.IssuerId
FROM Asset.Issuer i
INNER JOIN Asset.IssuerCustom ic ON i.CompanyId = ic.IssuerId;
```

[image]

As you can see, the query is using both the indices above. On the other hand, this same join occurs in a much larger query, and the below image shows the corner of the plan, where this join is occurring as a hash join:

[image]

The one difference that I can see is that there is a reversal in terms of which table is the "inner" table vs which is the "outer" table. Still, why would this impact the execution plan if both queries are inner joins on the same column?

Comment: Is it possible o make the non-clustered index a "covering" index by including the required INCLUDE columns to satisfy the SELECT/WHERE/ORDER BY requirements of the query?  Do the two tables being joined have roughly the same number of rows?  Are you certain in the 'large' query, that your specified indexes are being used in all those cases where you're seeing Hash-joins?

Comment: A `merge join` is only possible if both inputs are *already sorted* - otherwise, some other join (most often a hash join) will be chosen

Comment: I have never seen a case where a merge join was not used if it was applicable. It is cheaper per-row and has lower startup costs so it is always superior if applicable. Post the table definitions and actual execution plans. We surely will find a reason why a merge join is not applicable.

Comment: I added some more details. The large query is just too large to analyze, but the indexes and the rowcounts are shown above. One thing I pointed out is that the left / right orientation of the tables has changed, but both are inner joins, so it should not matter.

Comment: Statistics influence join choice as well.  Some joins are more efficient only if you have a large number of records, and thus it will use the number of estimated records to make a choice.

Comment: You can also use a join hint to try and force a merge join, and profile the query to see if it is actually faster.  I'm not sure if this will cause the query plan to generate sorts to facilitate this, but if it does that might help you see what you are missing that is preventing the merge join by default.

Comment: Excellent point @AaronLS I did just that and found that much of the execution plan for the larger query changed, where many (about a third) of the hash joins were replaced with merge joins. I suspect this is because the inputs from prior operations would be sorted as a result of the merge join, and that pushed the optimizer to use a merge instead. I t was not a whole lot faster, but comparable (according to the optimizer it is more expensive). Not entirely sure how to use that new plan to figure out what is missing though.

Comment: Try updating your statistics first just to make sure that's not the issue.

Comment: I think you answered yourself here: "(according to the optimizer it is more expensive)".  The optimizer thinks -- correctly or incorrectly -- that it's more expensive, so it switches to it's Hash Join "go to" method. The optimizer is not always right in every situation. But it's mostly right, and sounds like it's "close enough" in this situation.

Comment: In the second image the 1st table 2x as expensive to scan. In the first image it is the reverse. Are we looking at the same tables here? What predicates are on those scans? Are there bitmap probes? A hash join can build a bitmap on the build side. As part of a larger plan scans can also pick up predicates from elsewhere and run them directly in the access methods iterator.

Comment: Try to minimize your NCL_Asset_IssuerCustom_IssuerId index to have only  ListItem2Id and ListItem3Id included. Also try to find COUNT(DISTINCT col) for all the columns Asset.IssuerCompanyId and sort them in INCLUDE by DESC order.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Server Query optimiser does not guarantee the optimum query.  It looks for the best query in the time that it sets itself.  As queries become large, with multiple joins, the number of different combinations grows exponentially and it becomes impossible to explore every possible path and therefore guarantee an optimum solution.

Usually, you should be able to trust the query optimiser to do a good job if your table design is sound (with appropriate indices) and statistics are up to date.

The different choice of joins may be due to a different resources available - (CPU & memory) considering other parts of the plan being executed in parallel.

If you want to investigate further, I would test running with join hints to find out if the execution plan has made the best decision.  It may also be worth testing with the query hint MAXDOP=1 to find out if parallel execution effects the choices made by the optimiser.